# Connecting R to open office database using ODB

Tags: sql, r, hsqldb, odb

Despite several efforts I do not succeed to read my tables in an open office database in R.

I have loaded the ODB package. And connect using the command

```
con <- odb.open('Database.odb')
```

to connect
when i use the command

```
odb.tables(con)
```

The console shows me the following

```
$Datasets
    field.name field.type data.type comment
1           ID    INTEGER   numeric    <NA>
2 Dataset_naam    VARCHAR character    <NA>
3 Beschrijving    VARCHAR character    <NA>
4     Eigenaar    VARCHAR character    <NA>
5      Cluster       CHAR character    <NA>
6   Vindplaats    VARCHAR character    <NA>
```

Looks promising, however when I try to actually acces the table like this

```
odb.read(con, 'SELECT * FROM Datasets')
```

the following error is thrown.

```
Error: Error while executing SQL query  : "Unable to retrieve JDBC `result set for SELECT * FROM Datasets (Table not found in statement [SELECT * FROM Datasets])"`
```

Why can I not acces the table?

On the other hand if I try to create tables They do not show when I open the open office database.

Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What library are you using? Please include all library lines.

Comment: It looks like you need to use double quotes around the name of the table in the SELECT statement.

Comment: I use the ODB package. (This automatically loads DBI, rJava and RJDBC). But fredt is right! is needed to use the double quotation (I used both single quatation and not quoatation). I deeply appreciate your awnsers, I'm really glad that I can at last connect to my database!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must write the name of a table. Try the following:

`odb.read(con, 'SELECT * FROM Cluster')`

Comment: You answer is an exact replica of what the OP said they tried. How is `odb.read(con, 'SELECT * FROM Cluster')` different from `odb.read(con, 'SELECT * FROM Datasets')`?

Comment: I'm sorry. I make a mistake

Answer (score -1):

Your attempt was:

`odb.read(con, 'SELECT * FROM Datasets')`

...the '*' should be a table name, something like 'TableName', just like 'Datasets' seems to be a database name

so I am supposing that

`odb.read(con, 'SELECT TableName FROM Datasets')`

should work.

Answer (score -2):

You should try this...

```
print(odb.read(con, "SELECT * FROM Datasets"))
```